# Understanding bind in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select element with id settings-select.These are the two different ways I am binding event.Why is 'this' value not bound to select element even after using 'bind' in second method.

```
   1. 
    $('body').on( 'change', '#settings-select', function() {
        console.log( $(this).val ); // outputs correct select value
    });

   2.
    $('body').on( 'change', '#settings-select', selectSettings.bind( this ) );

    function selectSettings() {
        console.log( $(this).val() );// Throws error. this -> window object. Why?
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `bind`, `this` doesn't refers to current element. It refers to `window` object.

You just need to pass the function reference

```
$('body').on( 'change', '#settings-select', selectSettings)
```

As per comment, some argument to `selectSettings`. You can use [event.data](https://api.jquery.com/event.data/)

```js
var x = 1;
$('body').on('change', '#settings-select', {
  value: x
}, selectSettings)

function selectSettings(event) {
  console.log(event.data.value, $(this).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='settings-select'>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why does $(this).val() works inside selectSettings function in this case?Can you please explain?

Comment: In this scenario, `this` is set with current element context so it works

Comment: How can I pass arguments to selectSettings?

Comment: @johndoe, https://api.jquery.com/event.data/ updated answer with snippet

Answer (score 2):

> Throws error. this -> window object. Why?

Because, `$('body').on( 'change', '#settings-select', selectSettings.bind( this ) );` This particular code was executed in window's context. So there `this` would point to `window`.

And a rule behind `bind` function is, once you bound a context to a function using `bind`, then that wouldn't be changed to any after that.

Answer (score 0):

In the second method just pass the function callback reference like this

```
$('body').on( 'change', '#settings-select', selectSettings)
```

yes both are same functionality,  But there difference between the First method and second one,

1) It is an anonymous callback function.

```
 $('body').on( 'change', '#settings-select', function() {
        console.log( $(this).val() ); // outputs correct select value
 });
```

2) If you want reusable function go to second method then where want you to bind the same function

```
$('body').on( 'change', '#settings-select', selectSettings);

    function selectSettings() {
        console.log( $(this).val());
    }
```